Troubles booting Ubuntu Studio
I'm having a problem with starting last Ubuntu Studio version (24.04), it often happens that when I turn on the PC and start Ubuntu, I come across a completely black screen and it doesn't go any further, but if I turn it off and restart in "recovery" mode and do " Repair damaged packages" and "Clean Disk" Ubuntu finally starts, why does this happen? I would like it to boot in normal mode

did, edited, Ubuntu version: 24.04 lts
